# Raspberry PI with hidden static IP configuration

Tags: debian

I have a Raspberry PI 3 (with Stretch) that boots to a static IP. The problem is I can't find out where this IP is being configured.

Areas I have looked:

```
/etc/dhcpcd.conf
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/network/interfaces.d
/boot/commandline.txt
```

I have even done a `find`/`grep` on the root directory for the static IP. No luck. Any ideas?

Edit:

> ifconfig

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.10.90.201  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.10.95.255
...

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
....
```

Comment: How do you know it's not obtained via DHCP?

Comment: I should've mention that. It is presently not connected to a network.

Comment: What's the address then? Is it `169.254.aaa.bbb` maybe?

Comment: The address is 10.10.90.201

Comment: What does `sudo ifconfig` show for that IP address and interface? You might add the output of that to the question perhaps.

Comment: also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK I finally figured this out. Looks like the ip was being set via an rc.local program and it was pulling the ip address from a sqlite database which is why my global find on the ip did find it. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The standard thing to do in situations like this is to describe the solution (maybe in a little more detail, like: how did you find it?) and post it as an answer (i.e., in the “Your Answer” box, below).  Yes, you are allowed (and even encouraged) to answer your own question.  It might help somebody someday, and you might get a little “reputation” on this site for doing it.  Beware that comments are sometimes deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Newer releases of Debian (e.g. stretch) are managed through **systemd**, as explained in the [Debian Reference, Chapter 5: Network setup](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html):

> Under systemd, the network may be configured in `/etc/systemd/network/` instead.

The same document says:

> Debian **squeeze** and newer can manage the network connection via
>   management daemon software such as NetworkManager (NM)
>   (network-manager and associated packages) or Wicd (wicd and associated
>   packages).

I suggest you actually read the whole chapter, since it is essential for a thorough understanding of how Debian works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have avahi-daemon or connman installed? I have had this (similar) problem happen before, and disabling/uninstalling these two removed the issue.

If it's another service doing it, `dmesg | grep "10.10.90.201"` should unveil the culprit...