# Why does my Raspberry Pi have a static IP?

Tags: linux, ip, raspberry-pi

TLDR: RPi has a static IP. I can't locate where this is defined. Where should I look?

When I set up this Raspberry Pi I must have (sensibly?) configured a static IP. The Pi is always available on http://192.168.1.24 after reboots.

I now want to make some changes. Specifically I want to associate the static IP with eth0 rather than wlan0.

I expected that this would be a simple change in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. However, when I inspect this file it is still in its default state and all IP settings are commented out.

Now I am concerned that editing dhcpcd.conf might conflict with settings configured elsewhere. I want to identify where the static IP of http://192.168.1.24 is configured, so that I can understand what the impacts may be.

If the static IP is not defined in dhcpcd.conf, where else could it be?

So far I have:

- Checked `boot/cmdline.txt`,
- Confirmed that IP address is not being assigned by the router via
  DHCP,
- Run a grep from the root directory which only turned up log files.

My questions is quite similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1339055/raspberry-pi-with-hidden-static-ip-configuration), but I don't think there is any rc.local  program involved in my case.

How can I identify where this static IP is being set?

Comment: You only mention which SBC you have, and neglect to mention which distribution you have installed. What exactly did those log files report? Instead of **boot/cmdline.txt**, you should inspect **/proc/cmdline**, which contains the *actual* kernel parameters used. You need to first review logs, which report what was actually done, rather than focus on configuration files.

Comment: thanks @sawdust. I'm on Raspian 10. `/proc/cmdline` contains a number of parameters, but unfortunately non are IP related. Most of the logs I grepped are simple network activity logs, after going through these in detail the only entries that appear relevant are for dhcpcd daemon (wlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.49) and for avahi-daemon (Registering new address record for 192.168.1.49 on wlan0.IPv4.). `dhcpcd5.service` does not define the static IP. I am still looking into avahi but I don't believe this service is responsible for setting the IP address. Appreciate any more ideas you have?

Answer (score 1):

Look through all startup services (`systemctl list-dependencies` might help) and through all running services (`systemctl status system.slice`). There may be other network configuration services besides just dhcpcd (which is rarely used for static configuration anyway) – the most common ones are:

- Debian usually comes with "ifupdown" aka ifup@.service aka networking.service, which reads settings from `/etc/network/interfaces` (and interfaces.d).
- systemd-networkd (see `networkctl`), which reads `/etc/systemd/network`.
- NetworkManager (see `nmcli`), which reads `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.
- On Ubuntu, both networkd or NetworkManager may be receiving their configuration from Netplan, which reads `/etc/netplan`.
- Fedora and derivatives use ifcfg which reads `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` (often those files are processed by Fedora's version of NetworkManager instead of the actual ifcfg).

Comment: Thanks @user1686. I'm running Raspian/Debian. My `interfaces.d` directory is empty, does this service pick up settings from anywhere else? `etc/systemd/network` contains one file `99-default.link` which appears empty when read with nano, but also gives an error `is not a normal file`. `networkctl status` lists my IP address. How can I check whether networkctl is picking up any settings from anywhere?

Comment: By looking at the "Network File:" line in the status output. If a .network file is not listed there, then the interface was not configured by systemd-networkd (and the status should show "unmanaged" rather than "configured").

Comment: Yes, it is not configured. Indeed systemd-networkd is not running. Appreciate you taking the time to help. Are there any other locations you suggest looking?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, apologies if STBO. If there is no obvious static IP config on the device, have you checked your router to see of you had set a reserved address against the Rpi? Often used to be the quickest (and easiest) way when people were starting out with Rpi's!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).